# How do I make a countdown timer in Python without importing time?

Tags: python

I'm creating a countdown timer for a game in Python. My problem is I could only find code that uses `time.sleep()`, which pauses the entire code. Is there a way to make a countdown timer, for example, from 60 seconds. Is it possible to use millis()?

Comment: You can use sleep if you combine it with a `threading.Thread`

Comment: Are you open to suggestions using `time`, but not `time.sleep()`?

Comment: what are you actually trying to acheive with your timer? does the game end or something? how is your game running ? in a loop? maybe post your code and explain what your trying to do. might be better to create a start time and then compare that to current time and when current time - start time exceeds 60 do some action

Comment: Yeah I am open to anything, doesn't even have to use the time library.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to make the game stop after 60 seconds.

Comment: you could do something like `start_time = time.time(); while time.time() - start_time < 60: `

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep()` makes your program wait some time and not do anything.
The way it's usually done is to use something like `time.time()` to get the current time and as your title says: 'count down' from there using your loop and getting the difference between the start value and the current value of `time.time()`. If it's greater than your desired value, then just simply break out of the loop.

Comment: Is it possible to text the countdown out to the screen?

Comment: Sure you can, `time.time()` gives you seconds since the epoch, so their difference will be still in the seconds range. You need to measure if 1 second has passed inside the loop, the same way you are checking for the elapsed time. And if 1 second has passed then print the value of the difference to the start time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a game loop that runs every tick of your program, you could have a Countdown class whose `countdownElapsed` function gets called every tick of your game loop and that checks when your countdown is at zero

```
// Pseudo-code
func countdownElapsed(countdown):
    return (countdown.lastTime - time.currentTime()) < 0
```

You could also create a Scheduler class that stores a bunch of function pointers, their arguments and the time you want to call said function pointers inside a vector of some sort and does the check above for every function inside the vector every tick.

Finally, you can also just have a separate thread where you sleep and time-sensitive tasks.